# systemd sleep.conf: perform IdleAction only on battery

Tags: linux, systemd, power-management, suspend

When I'm running on battery power, I'd like to have `IdleAction=suspend-then-hibernate`.

However, if mains power is connected, I'd like to have `IdleAction=ignore`.

How would I go about setting this up?